# Why does Rust allow public access to a private module?

Tags: module, rust, public

I am a newbie in Rust and just started to read the programming book while doing `rustling` exercises. In the `modules2.rs` exercise, I am confused why the following code compiles:

```rust
mod delicious_snacks {
    pub use self::fruits::PEAR as fruit;
    pub use self::veggies::CUCUMBER as veggie;

    mod fruits {
        pub const PEAR: &'static str = "Pear";
        pub const APPLE: &'static str = "Apple";
    }

    mod veggies {
        pub const CUCUMBER: &'static str = "Cucumber";
        pub const CARROT: &'static str = "Carrot";
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!(
        "favorite snacks: {} and {}",
        delicious_snacks::fruit,
        delicious_snacks::veggie
    );
}
```

Specifically, I am wondering why it is OK for `main` to access private `fruits` and `veggies` modules just because their `use`s are marked `pub`? On the other hand, if we don't use `pub use`, then, without making `fruits` and `veggies` `pub`, one cannot access e.g., `delicious_snacks::fruits::PEAR` in `main` because `fruits` is not public. Similarly, if we don't use `pub` for `const PEAR`, even with `pub use self::fruits::PEAR as fruit`, we still cannot compile `delicious_snacks::fruit`. So what exactly is the rule here? Why is it OK to not mark `pub` for those modules?

Comment: Did you read the two first line inside your module ? BTW avoid line number

Comment: @Stargateur Yes I did read the first two lines inside my module. In fact, I even mentioned them in my question. I was just confused how `pub use` and private modules work together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constants `PEAR/APPLE/CUCUMBER/CARROT` are marked as `pub`, which means they can be accessed from everywhere, even if they're in a private module.

This is a common technique, to implement something in a private module, and re-export only the things we want, e.g.

```rust
// actual implementation is here
mod foo_internal;

pub use foo_internal::{Foo, Bar};
```

This still maintains privacy/visibility, since `Foo` and `Bar` can't be re-exported if they're private.

You can also create a new module hierarchy for users of your library:

```rust
mod foo_internal;

pub mod foo {
    pub use foo_internal::Foo;
}

pub mod bar {
    pub use foo_internal::Bar;
}
```

This clearly separates the *public interface* from *implementation details*, so the implementation can be freely refactored without changing the public modules.

Comment: The constants `PEAR/APPLE/CUCUMBER/CARROT` are marked as `pub`, but for example, `main()` cannot access them through `delicious_snacks::fruits::PEAR` (without `pub use`), which you will get: `error[E0603]: module fruits is private` from compiler. So I don't think marking a constant `pub` allows it to be accessed from *everywhere*, if they are in a private module. I think maybe it has something to do with `pub use`?Is there some rule in Rust like: if a struct/constant/enum/fn is marked pub, and is exported through `pub use`, then it can be accessed anywhere even if they are in private module?

Comment: @wasabigreenpeas Yes, the module `fruits` is private, but its contents are not. By re-exporting them, they can still be accessed, as you can observe in the above example. Note that `pub use` not only brings an item into scope, but it also _re-exports_ it, so it can be accessed from outside the module.